# Behaviour of instance_eval

Tags: ruby

My understanding of `instance_eval` was that if I have module M then the following were equivalent:

```
module M
  def foo
    :foo
  end
end

class C
  class << self
    include M
  end
end
puts C.foo
```

equivalent to:

```
module M
  def foo
    :foo
  end
end

class C
end
C.instance_eval do
  include M
end
puts C.foo
```

However, the first example prints `:foo` and the second throws a `NoMethodError`? (Ruby 2.3.0)

In both cases above, if I had replaced:

```
include M
```

with:

```
def foo
  :foo
end
```

ie directly defining the method rather than including a module then both cases would have resulted in a `C.foo` method being defined. Should I be surprised at this difference between include and defining the method directly?
Or does it ever even make sense to call include within the context of `instance_eval`? Should it only ever be called within a `class_eval`?

Comment: your first example is actually more equivalent to `C.instance_eval { extend M }`

Answer (score 2):

In each of these cases, what object are you calling `include` on? In your first example, you're calling `include` on C's singleton class:

```
class C
  class << self
    p self == C.singleton_class
    include M
  end
end
# => true

p C.foo
# => :foo
```

...so your `include` line is equivalent to `C.singleton_class.include(M)`.

In your second example, however, you're calling `include` on C itself:

```
class C
end
C.instance_eval do
  p self == C
  include M
end
# => true

p C.foo
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for C:Class

p C.new.foo
# => :foo
```

...so you're doing the equivalent of `C.include(M)`, which is the same as:

```
class C
  p self == C
  include M
end
# => true

p C.new.foo
# => :foo
```

What *would* work like you want would be to call `instance_eval` on C's singleton class:

```
class D
end
D.singleton_class.instance_eval do
  p self == D.singleton_class
  include M
end
# => true

p D.foo
# => :foo
```

Comment: Or, to make it closer to original code, `class << D; self; end.instance_eval {}`.

Comment: *"so your include line is equivalent to C.singleton_class.include(M)"* not necessarily true. This actually injects M into `C` call hierarchy e.g. `C.ancestors #=> [C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]` where as the initial implementation is actually more equivalent to `C.extend(M)`

Comment: Thanks very much, that's very helpful! I think then my confusion might actually be the behaviour of include:
In both of the cases, if I had used `def foo; :foo; end` directly instead of `include M`, I believe it would have defined C.foo rather than C.new.foo.
I find this disparity between include and direct definition surprising

Comment: @TimSpence You're right, [that's what it would have done](https://repl.it/JHYu). I agree that the disparity is surprising.

Answer (score 0):

`Module#class_eval()` is very different from `Object#instance_eval()`. The `instance_eval()` only changes `self`, while `class_eval()` changes both `self` and the `current class`.

Unlike in your example, you can alter class_instance vars using `instance_eval` though, because they are in the object scope as `MyClass` is a singleton instance of class `Class`.

```
class MyClass
  @class_instance_var = 100
  @@class_var = 100

  def self.disp
    @class_instance_var
  end

  def self.class_var
    @@class_var
  end


  def some_inst_method
    12
  end
end

MyClass.instance_eval do
  @class_instance_var = 500

  def self.cls_method
    @@class_var = 200
    'Class method added'
  end

  def inst_method
    :inst
  end
end

MyClass.disp
#=> 500

MyClass.cls_method
#=> 'Class method added'

MyClass.class_var
#=> 100

MyClass.new.inst_method
# undefined method `inst_method' for #<MyClass:0x0055d8e4baf320>
```

### In simple language.

If you have a look in the upper class defn code as an interpreter, you notice that there are two scopes `class scope` and `object scope`. **class vars** and **instance methods** are accessible from `object scope` and does not fall under jurisdiction of `instance_eval()` so it skips such codes.

Why? because, as the name suggests, its supposed to alter the `Class`'s instance(MyClass)'s properties not other object's properties like `MyClass`'s any object's properties. Also, class variables don’t really belong to classes—they belong to class hierarchies.

---

If you want to open an object that is not a class, then you can
safely use `instance_eval()`. But, if you want to open a class definition and define methods with `def` or `include` some module, then `class_eval()` should be your pick.

By changing the `current class`, `class_eval()` effectively reopens the class, just like the `class` keyword does. And, this is what you are trying to achieve in this question.

```
MyClass.class_eval do
  def inst_method
    :inst
  end
end

MyClass.new.inst_method
#=> :inst
```

Comment: Your first three paragraphs talk about `class_eval`; your answer would benefit by some example code that actually uses `class_eval`.

Comment: sure Jordan I will

Comment: You did not address inclusion at all which seems to be the premise of the post. e.g. Why inclusion in `class << self` extends the class but inclusion inside `instance_eval` does not